# Javascript getDay method returns wrong number

Tags: javascript

Here is a small html/javascript which I tested in browsers and node.js(similar). You can see last row is not same (I don't know, maybe only on my machine). Perhaps something is generally wrong with the javascript code or am I doing something wrong?

HTML

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Script

```
function myFunction()
{
    var strng="";
    for (var i=25;i<32;i++){
        var d = new Date();
        d.setFullYear(2013, 11, i);
        var dt = new Date();
        dt.setDate(i);
        dt.setMonth(11);    
        dt.setYear(2013);
        strng += d.toLocaleDateString() + "  -  " + d.getDay() + " : " + dt.getDay() +" <br>";   
    }
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML=strng;
}
```

Comment: getDay give you 0 - 6 sunday - sat

Comment: use getDate(); to get date

Answer (score 6):

If you set the Day first before month, you will get for the last date Dec 1st.
This is because `new Date()` returns the current date from today(28.Nov).
As November only has 30 days, `setDate(31)` will set the Date to 1st of Dec instead of 31th

I first got the question wrong, but for completeness I will keep this answer here too:

To get the Day you have to use `getDate()` this will return you the day of the month you wanted to have.

`getDay()` returns the wrong number because it is used to get the day of the week. (like 6 for saturday)

Comment: You didn't answer the question, after your last edit!

Comment: I first got the problem wrong, but therefor i added the last paragraph about the problem with nov the 30th. You'll get a upvote from me too, because ou got the Problem right instantly ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when call `dt.setDate(i)` before `dt.setMonth(11)`, if you inverts those line it works well ...this is bacause `new Date()` return date in current month which is November and only have 30 days, so when you set date to 31 it changes to the December 1st day, so you are comparing differents days of weeks: December 1st and December 31